# code problem code not run and i can't solve the problem

Tags: counter, toolkit

[hi everyone my code not work and i don't know the problem . thank you](https://github.com/abednebi/counter.git)

Comment: Please give a [mre]. What _langauge_, even? Read [ask] (and maybe do the [tour] again more carefully).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)
Also add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Images of code are totally useless, and so is the problem description *does not work*. Please provide your actual code here, in the question itself as text, and add a clearly stated problem description, the **exact, complete error message** if you're seeing one, and ask a **specific question** related to the code you've posted. Explaining the problem and including your code and asking the question is your responsibility,  and we can't do our part to help you until you've done your part.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to remove `{ }` from line 7 of `Counter.js` and replace it with this line:

```
const value = useSelector(state  => state.Counter)
```

Comment: Answering questions that do not contain appropriate content isn't helpful, because it removes all incentive for the OP to edit the post to improve it.